# What's the best way to embed IronPython inside my C# App?

Tags: c#, .net, ironpython, dynamic-language-runtime

I have an application used by pretty tech-savey people and they want small island of programmability so I've used embedded Iron Python.

However, since IronPython 2.0 Eval() doesn't work any more. Specifically I can't both load modules and inject local variables.

There is a work around where I can still call Execute(), print out my answer and listen to StandardOut, but then it comes out as a string and I've lost the type.

Not a disaster for a long, but a huge pain for more complex objects.

Does anyone know how to get Eval() working again in 2.0 like it did in 1.x?

Cheers,
Jan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you be a little more specific about the problem, and maybe provide a code example?  The "eval"-style functionality is definitely still present, though as you've noticed, the hosting interface has changed considerably since 1.0.

This works in beta 5:

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString("2 + 5", SourceCodeKind.Expression);
int result = source.Execute<int>();
```

By the way, using the right `SourceCodeKind` is critical here.

Comment: I'm on Beta 4, is it worth going to 5?

Comment: The hosting interfaces in beta 5 are almost final.  I don't remember how much they changed between 4 and 5, but I'm pretty sure there was *some* change. RC1 will be out in about a week.

Answer (score 1):

This example may help you: http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/dlr_hosting.shtml

Comment: Thanks Antonio, that's effectively what I have running at the moment :)